# Please check my proof of $A \times (B - C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \times (B - C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$

Firstly i assume that each of sets are non empty. Having said that assume $(x,y) \in A \times (B - C) $. So $x \in A$ and $y \in (B-C)$. So $y \in B$ and $y \notin C$. So $(x,y) \in A \times B $ and $(x,y) \notin A \times C$. So $(x,y) \in (A \times B) - (A \times C)$. Other direction can be proved by just simply working backwards

Thanks

Comment: $B-C$ means set complement $B\setminus C$

Comment: Seems to me that your proof is correct.

Comment: @Wuestenfux (B-C) means set which has elements of B and not C

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(x,y)\in A\times (B\setminus C)$ iff $x\in A$ and $y\in B\setminus C$ iff
$(x\in A)\wedge (y\in B\wedge y\not\in C)$ iff $(x\in A\wedge y\in B)\wedge (x\in A\wedge y\not\in C)$ iff $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(x,y)\not\in A\times C$. Done

Comment: Isn't this is what i have written?

Comment: Set equalities can often be proved by equivalence statements. No need to distinguish between empty and nonempty sets.

Comment: Okey thanks....